# Kicad - 0805 Hand soldered package

Tags: resistors, surface-mount, kicad, packages

When I try to select a footprint for an 0805 resistor in Kicad, there are two options.

[image]

What is the difference between them and which one do I choose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like the name suggest, the second option is optimized for soldering by hand. The pads are a bit bigger on this version to allow for higher tolerances when soldering. The disadvantage of this is that you can't pack the parts as densely on the PCB. There is also higher probability that it won't be straightened nicely by surface tension when using solder paste and reflow soldering.

So in general, use the first one when you use automated soldering processes like reflow soldering and second one when you solder with a solder iron by hand. Personally, I think the “normal” footprint is fine for hand soldering as well, if you’re not a beginner.

Comment: If you have a bevel tip with untinned sides even a beginner can do it. It holds really tightly to the molten bead and while forcing it to protrude unusually far to allow you to get under components. The bead squishes out to reach and fill gaps like squeezing a water balloon balloon in your hand and having it force out between the gaps in your fingers. But it still recedes with the iron when you pull the tip away. It's like having a tip made of liquid metal rather than a solid tip that has been wetted; Kind of like a T1000.